# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel with IEnumerable Property

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

**What I am Attempting**

I am trying to bind my ViewModel to my View which contains a Customer Name and a list of Contacts to reach that customer. Once the view is populated I also want the user to have the ability to add, delete, and edit contacts in the View.

**What I've got so far**

Currently I am able to bind to the ViewModel using the EditorTemplate and edit the data with no problems. The problem comes in when I want to add or remove rows in the list, if a user deletes row 5 from the middle of the ViewModel bound Editable List only rows 1 - 4 will end up being posted to the server.

**The Code**

Here is what my ViewModel looks like:

```
    public class CustomerViewModel{
       [Required]
       public int CustomerUniqueID { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public IEnumerable<CustomerContacts> Contacts { get; set; }

       public CustomerViewModel() { }
       public CustomerViewModel(Customer customer)
       {
        ICustomerContactRepository contacts = new LockShop.Domain.Concrete.EFCustomerContactRepository();
        this.Contacts = contacts.FindContacts(customer.UniqueID);

        this.Name = customer.Name;
    }
}
```

I am passing my ViewModel to my view like this:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(){
           Customer customer = repository.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UniqueID == 23128);
           return View(new CustomerViewModel(customer));            
        }
```

When it is time to render the list, I simply use the EditorFor helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contacts)
```

What I love about this approach is that when I click the save button all of my changes are automatically posted to the controller!

**My Question**

What are the best practices of how to add the functionality of adding and removing rows to a list that is generated by an IEnumerable from my ViewModel?

**What I Have Tried**

I've read Steven Sanderson's blog post which talks about [editing a variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) in ASP.NET MVC. His post seems to only cover binding to a model and doesn't cover the possibility of binding to a list in a ViewModel. When I implemented his solution the post data from the Contacts list that got sent back to the controller was null.

Please feel free to ask any questions for clarification and thanks for your time.